# How to make a sequential API call in RX

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I started reading about RX on Android . I was trying to do a POST api call from within a rx chain. I wanted to see if this is the right way and that do I need to even create a disposable again when making the call and register the subscribe/observe threads again. Please see the comments in the code.

```
disposable.add(module.getInfo()
.flatMapSingleElement {
  profile ->
    profile.getDetails().map {
      //IS THIS NEW DISPOSABLE NEEDED
      newDisposable.add(
    //Retrofit api to return Single<ResponseBody>
    //IS THIS THE RIGHT WAY TO MAKE A SEQUENTIAL API CALL IN RX CONSUMING DATA FROM ANOTHER OPERATOR
    module.saveImageDetails(
        ImageDetails(imageId)
        subscribeOn(Schedulers.io().observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(
                Consumer { handleResponse(it) },
                createErrorHandler()
            )
    )
      profile
    }
}
.subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
.observeOn(uiScheduler)
.subscribe(//do something)
```

Comment: Subscribing inside such lambda is always a code smell. Use `flatMap` instead. See also https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows